# JavaScript Random Number Between 15 and 225 Increments of 30?

Tags: javascript, math, random

Hi I need to generate a random number in JavaScript between 15 and 225 that can only be by increments of 30. For example: 45, 75, 105 etc.

Any ideas on how this can be done? I'm aware of `Math.floor(Math.random()*11)` for example for a random number 1-10 but how can this be modified to fit in with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*11)` will return a number `[0-10]`, whereas `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1` will return a number `[1-10]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think about the final outcome that you want. Between 15 and 225 is what you want to aim for, but not what you need to be working with to get the result.

225/30 = 7.5. 15 is half of 30. Therefore, (225-15)/30 = 7. You want a random number between 1 and 7, which you will then multiply by 30 and add 15 to the final result.

```
var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
myNumber = myNumber *30 + 15;

console.log(myNumber);
```

Comment: I really don't mind not getting the accepted answer, but this one is actually wrong. You will never get 225, just fyi

Comment: It should really be `var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*8);`.

Answer (score 9):

Like so

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*8)*30 + 15
```

Comment: getting this answer requires the highschool algebra that most students never expect to use.

Answer (score 7):

how about using:

```
[15, 45, 75, 105, 135, 165, 195, 225][Math.floor(Math.random()*8)]
```

Comment: I like this one the best based on the [**KISS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle

Comment: well, i was thinking `random.choice(range(15,225+1,30))` and this is the javascript of that.

Comment: This is a great technique for when you want to randomize a selection of non-linear values, such as picking a random coin, or dollar bill.

Answer (score 7):

Start with the table of values

```
x |   y
=======
0 |  15
1 |  45
2 |  75
3 | 105
4 | 135
5 | 165
6 | 195
7 | 225
```

Set up the equation

```
y = ax + b
```

Plug in some initial values

```
15 = a(0) + b
```

Solve for any variables you can

```
15 = b
```

Plug in different initial values

```
225 = a(7) + 15
```

Solve for any remaining variables

```
210 = a(7)
30 = a
```

Restate the equation

```
y = 30x + 15
```

Randomize `x` between the limits

```
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) //0-7
```

Use in function

```
function customRandomNumber() {
    var x;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    return 30 * x + 15;
}
```

Getting a random number within an interval with a step can be generalized in the following function:

```
function rand(min, max, step) {
    var delta,
        range,
        rand;
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        max = min;
        min = 0;
    }
    if (!step) {
        step = 1;
    }
    delta = max - min;
    range = delta / step;
    rand = Math.random();
    rand *= range;
    rand = Math.floor(rand);
    rand *= step;
    rand += min;
    return rand;
}
```

Which would put your function as

```
rand(15, 225, 30);
```

---

I should also note, because I'd forgotten about the possible bounds issues, the generalized form will *not* include the upper bound of 225. This is because `Math.random()` returns a number greater than, or equal to zero and *less than* one (`0 <= Math.random < 1`). If you *want* to include the upper bound, you simply need to include one more step in the interval:

```
rand(15, 255, 30) //will return 15...225
```

Comment: `y = mx + b` not `y = ax + b` :)

Comment: @qwertymk, the variable names you use don't actually matter. I could have written `foo = fizz*bar + buzz` and it would get you the same results. The only reason students are taught the convention of `y=mx+b` is so that we can give a consistent name to variables for ease of reference.

Comment: My understanding is that in some countries, especially The United States of America, `y = mx + b` is standard, whereas in other countries, such as those in the European Union, `y = ax + b` is standard.
Either way, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic version.

```
function randomIntInSteps(a, b, step) {
  function randomInt(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
  }

  if (a > b) {
    // Ensure a is smaller.
    var c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }

  step = Math.abs(step)

  return a + randomInt(0, Math.floor((b - a)/step)) * step;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
randomIntInSteps(1, 20, 5); // possible results: 1, 6, 11, 16
randomIntInSteps(1, 21, 5); // possible results: 1, 6, 11, 16, 21
```

It will also work with negatives:

```
randomIntInSteps(-10, 11, 5); // possible results: -10, -5, 0, 5, 10
randomIntInSteps(-20, -9, 5); // possible results: -20, -15, -10
```

Using floats can be problematic because of floating point errors:

```
randomIntInSteps(1.1, 5.5, 2.2); // possible results: 1.1, 3.3000000000000003, 5.5
```

To overcome the floating point problem, you can convert the numbers to integers before finding a random number, then convert back. Here's how (note: this depends on the `randomIntInSteps` function above, so you still need that):

```
function decimalPlaces(number) {
  var parts = (number + '').split('.');
  return parts.length > 1 ? parts[1].length : 0;
}

function wholeNumberMultiple(numbers) {
  return Math.max(...numbers.map(n => decimalPlaces(n)));
}

function randomNumber(a, b, step) {
  var multiple = Math.pow(10, wholeNumberMultiple([a, b]));
  return randomIntInSteps(a * multiple, b * multiple, step * multiple) / multiple;
}
```

You'll now get the desired results:

```
randomNumber(1.1, 5.5, 2.2); // possible results: 1.1, 3.3, 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that precomputes all possible numbers, and randomly returns one.

```
function getRandomNumber(start, end, increments) {
    var numbers = [];
    for(var n = start; n <= end; n += increments) {
        numbers.push(n);
    }

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    return numbers[randomIndex];
}
```

Use as,

```
getRandomNumber(15, 225, 30)
```